# Grub 2 incident

Tags: linux, fedora, grub2

I'm a fedora Linux user. And right now I am having trouble to boot the OS from  grub.
All I see is 4 kernels. And when I press return key
It shows:

> error:../../grub-core/script/lexer.c:337:syntax error

> Error:../../grub-core/script/lexer.c:337:incorrect command

The only think I noticed is that I installed Fedora 33 but for some reason it shows fedora 32

Could someone please tell me a solution? How can I boot?

B.R.

Comment: What happens if you press Enter (in the topmost row)? Perhaps the newest version of the OS will be booted?  It is normal that older variants will be shown - as options to boot if the newest version creates problems (failover). Also, please do not post images (see guidelines/help section of Stack Exchange).

Comment: I edit my? post could you check please

Comment: @Ned64 By the way before that, even though I upgraded my system from 32 to 33, It was not showing F32 option

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that's more helpful now. Does any other entry enable boot? If so which one? The text in the GRUB2 entries is generated by your newer system (Fedora 33) so it's not a problem if it is written differently. That is still likely your old kernel offered as a boot option.

Comment: Yes, all give the same error

Comment: These suggest the GRUB2 install might have been problematic and needs to be repeated in a rescue system: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636492 https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1637055 https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?321765-Mysterious-Grubby-Beasts-and-How-to-Fix-Them  -- Please note that the reason why `grub2-install` failed might have been different!  The effect is the same.